# Setup and user priviledges for content delivery with Oracle on Amazon RDS

Tags: 2013-sp1, oracle

I've been trying to get an Oracle content delivery database configured in Amazon's RDS service.

When you create a DB instance [on RDS], you create a master account that gets DBA privileges (with some limitations) and the SYS password or SYSDBA privileges are not provided. This limitations prevents the successful completion of the installation scripts. See the screenshot output of the `CreateTridionSYSUser.sql` script.

[image]

Has anyone successfully installed CD on Amazon's RDS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found a [very informative answer by Nuno](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/5064/23) on this subject. It seems that Oracle can not be used with cloud service providers such as RDS and Azure due to this specific problem with limitations on the master user account.

If you are wanting to go down the path of setting up their own Oracle 12c database on Amazon EC2 [I have written a three part guide](http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/content-delivery-on-redhat-linux-with-oracle-12c-part-1) on the process aimed at people without much Linux and Oracle experience